# Precise definition of 'Network egress region' for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The price sheet for Google Cloud storage lists different bandwidth tariffs for outbound traffic to EU/US vs Asia/Pacific.

Do these tariffs apply based on the location settings of the GCS bucket, or do they apply based on the location of the requestor?

I presume the former, but I can't find any definitive documentation.

It seems conceivable that an Asia based user could be directed to a local replica of a US based bucket, for example.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it is not programming-related.

Comment: Google's FAQ specifically state that support questions should be raised on stackoverflow - https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/faq#pricing

Comment: A 3rd party redirecting users to StackOverflow does not make all questions regarding that 3rd party to be on-topic for StackOverflow. Also, that's specifically for *technical* support; [here's where to go](https://support.google.com/cloudbilling/#topic=2991963) for billing-related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing is based on network traffic **destination** (in your case, that's the location of the requester), not the GCS bucket **location**. The documentation is not as clear on this as it should be, but will be updated soon.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

---

**Update:** [Google Cloud Storage network pricing](https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing) table headers have been updated to include the word "destinations" to clarify this (emphasis mine):

> Network (Egress) - Americas and EMEA* **Destinations** (per GB)
>
> Network (Egress) - Asia-Pacific **Destinations** (per GB)

Google Cloud Storage pricing for storage itself remains [independent of bucket location](https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing).

Comment: Is it possible to determine the request region from the GCS access logs? The documentation lists a c_ip_region field that is reserved for future use. The billing region is crucial for our purposes.

Comment: @AlexMcAusland I don't know what the future plans are for that field nor when it will be populated, so if I were you, I would use the `c_ip` field and then perform a coarse mapping from IP to country or region on my own, using a database for lookup. Note that such a DB will need licensing and regular updates to keep it accurate, but again, you need *region-level* which should be fairly easy; most uses are looking for metro-level geo-location.

Comment: thanks, that's what we decided to do. For anyone else so affected, MaxMind have a free (offline) database and associated client library readers.